# Which is the react way of complex conditional rendering?

Tags: reactjs

### Issue

I have a problem with conditional rendering of a component. As far as I can see, there are 2 approaches to doing this. First approach is ugly as it becomes difficult when I have to do multiple && conditions. The second way is clear, but it adds the component itself to the state and further computations with the state value is difficult. E.g checking what is the message value for error.

I have given both the approaches below. Please let me know which would be better. Is there a another approach than both of them?

### Application

This is a simple application that renders either 'Main' component or 'Err' component, based on the state of 'err' attribute in first approach and content of the comp attribute in second approach.

Initially Main component is rendered. The err attribute is updated to some value after 2 seconds, which triggers rerendering. At this time, I want Err component to render.

The real application is I have an external api call on componentDidMount and it can either fail or succeed. I have to display different components based on result. It is a little more complicated with multiple state values being updated. I have simplified the issue below for the purpose of demonstration.

## Common steps for both types

```
npx create-react-app react-oop
```

### component/Err.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

class Err extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                Error Component
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default Err
```

### component/Main.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Main extends Component {
    render(){
        return( 
            <div>
                Main Component
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Main
```

> ## First approach

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Err from './components/Err'
import Main from './components/Main'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      err: null
    }
  this.setError = this.setError.bind(this)
  }

  setError(){
    return(
      this.setState(() => {
        return({
          err: 'Error'
        })
      })
    )
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(this.setError, 2000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       { 
         this.state.err ? <Err /> : <Main />
       }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

> ## Second approach

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Err from './components/Err'
import Main from './components/Main'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      comp: <Main />
    }
  this.setError = this.setError.bind(this)
  }

  setError(){
    return(
      this.setState(() => {
        return({
          comp: <Err />
        })
      })
    )
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(this.setError, 2000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       {this.state.comp}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I definitely recommend the 1st approach. Store data (json), not views (jsx) in your component's state.

Actually there is a 3rd approach that takes the best of both:

> **use a jsx variable to edit the view (with your logic) before rendering**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Err from './components/Err';
import Main from './components/Main';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            err: null
        };
    }

    // This way of writing functions saves you the binding
    setError = () => this.setState({err: 'Error'})

    componentDidMount(){
        setTimeout(this.setError, 2000);
    }

    render() {
        let comp = <Main />;
        // Put your logic here so your returned JSX is clear
        if (this.state.err)
            comp = <Err />;
        return (
            <div className="App">
              {comp}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I think I will use this style, coupled with switch statements when there are multiple if conditions

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are essentially the same but I prefer option 1 as it's simpler to grasp. You can also use something like [babel-plugin-jsx-control-statements#choose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-jsx-control-statements#choose) which makes the React component look simpler:

```
<Choose>
  <When condition={ test1 }>
    <Main />
  </When>
  <When condition={ test2 }>
    <AnotherMain />
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <Err />
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

Comment: JSP in React :/